# Android Stuido sqlite database no such table error

Tags: java, android-sqlite

I'm trying to use sq lite database in android studio, but I get no such table error

I created an sqlite database and I was waiting for the database I created to assign data to the recycler view and for the tasks I created to appear in the recycler view. but I got no such table error and nothing showed up in the recycler view

```
private void saveWorkRecord() {
    
    String workName = editTextTaskName.getText().toString();
    int workingHours = 0; 
    int logoId = selectedLogoResourceId; 
    Date date = new Date(); 
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
    String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date); 

    try {
        database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS workifydatabase(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,workname VARCHAR,logoid INTEGER,year VARCHAR,workinghours INTEGER) ");
        String sqlString = "INSERT INTO workifydatabase(workname, logoid, year, workinghours) VALUES(?,?,?,?)";
        SQLiteStatement sqLiteStatement = database.compileStatement(sqlString);
        sqLiteStatement.bindString(1, workName);
        sqLiteStatement.bindLong(2, logoId); 
        sqLiteStatement.bindString(3, formattedDate);
        sqLiteStatement.bindLong(4, workingHours); 
        sqLiteStatement.executeInsert();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    database.close();
    finish();
}
```

and this is the usage part:

```
private void getData() {

    try {
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = requireContext().openOrCreateDatabase("workifyDatabase",MODE_PRIVATE,null);
        Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM workifydatabase",null);
        int nameIx = cursor.getColumnIndex("workname");
        int idIx = cursor.getColumnIndex("id");
        int hourIx = cursor.getColumnIndex("workinghours");
        int yearIx = cursor.getColumnIndex("year");

        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            String name = cursor.getString(nameIx);
            int id= cursor.getInt(idIx);
            String year = cursor.getString(yearIx);
            int hour = cursor.getInt(hourIx);
            Task task = new Task(name,id,hour,year);
            TaskArrayList.add(task);
        }

        taskAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        cursor.close();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that your issue is that the `getData` method is dependant upon the `saveWorkRecord` method (as this appears to create the database and then save to a non existent table) and that the saveWorkRecord method is dependant upon the getData method (as this appears to require that the database exists).

I would suggest that you consider the following demo that utilises the `SQLiteOpenHelper` class that helps you to open the database and passes control, when the database is first opened, to the `onCreate` method.

The demo also uses a singleton for the database.

**Working Demo**

First the `DBOpenHelper` class that is an extension of the `SQLiteOpenHelper` class:-

```
class DBOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

   public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "workifyDatabase";
   public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

   /* Constructor  for the DBOpenHelper class, private to force use of singleton */
   private DBOpenHelper(Context context) {
      super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
   }

   /* Singleton approach (i.e. only 1 instance of DBOpenHelper exists)*/
   private static volatile DBOpenHelper instance;
   public static DBOpenHelper getInstance(Context context) {
      if (instance==null) {
         instance = new DBOpenHelper(context);
      }
      return instance;
   }

   /* If the database does not exist, then this method will be called */
   /* ideal place to create the table(s) */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
      db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS workifydatabase(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,workname VARCHAR,logoid INTEGER,year VARCHAR,workinghours INTEGER) ");
   }

   /* If the database version is increased, then this method will be invoked */
   @Override
   public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
   }

   /* Method to insert a row, using the convenience insert method */
   /* this generates the underlying SQL and furthermore returns the id of the inserted row or -1 if the row was not inserted */
   public long saveWorkRecord(String workname,int logoid, String year,int workinghours) {
      ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
      cv.put("workname",workname);
      cv.put("logoid",logoid);
      cv.put("year",year);
      cv.put("workinghours",workinghours);
      return this.getWritableDatabase().insert("workifydatabase",null,cv);
   }

   /* Example of retrieving data (might want to adapt this to return a TaskArrayList rather than a Cursor) */
   public Cursor getAllDataAsCursor() {
      return this.getWritableDatabase().query("workifydatabase",null /* all columns */,null /* all rows*/,null /* no selection args */, null,null,null);
   }
}
```

- Note the two methods for accessing the database, `saveWorkRecord` for saving a row of data (returning the id of the row or -1 if the row could not be inserted and `getAllData` to return a Cursor (note the comment adapting to return a TaskArrayList). *i.e. the demo is more about circumventing the table not found issue than handling the display of the list*

To actually demonstrate some activity code that will save two records and then extract them from the database into a Cursor and then using the `DatabaseUtils` dumpCursor method to write the data in the cursor to the log:-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DBOpenHelper db;
    /*NOTE BAD IDEA TO STORE DATES in dd-mm-yyyy format
    * 1) date is only sortable indirectly
    * 2) the date, not being an SQLite recognised format, excludes simple use of SQLite's build in date functions
    *  */
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
    SimpleDateFormat beterDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd",Locale.getDefault());

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        db = DBOpenHelper.getInstance(this); /* get an instance of the DBOpenHelper*/
        /* Note that the database will not have been opened/created at this stage */

        /* Try to get data from the database (noting no data has been added) */
        /* This will result in the database being created (opened if it exists) and therefore
            the onCreate method of the DBOpenHelper instance being called, thus creating the table */
        Cursor csr = db.getAllDataAsCursor();
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(csr); /* Dumpy the cursor (will be empty first time the app is run) */

        /* Add two records */
        db.saveWorkRecord("My First Work Record",1,dateFormat.format(new Date()),0);
        db.saveWorkRecord("My Other First Work Record",2,beterDateFormat.format(new Date()),10);

        /* Extract the data and dump the cursor to the log */
        csr = db.getAllDataAsCursor();
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(csr);
    }
}
```

When run for the first time then the log includes:-

```
2023-08-17 08:19:59.993 I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@98fd0f5
2023-08-17 08:19:59.993 I/System.out: <<<<<



2023-08-17 08:19:59.995 I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@664ce8a
2023-08-17 08:19:59.996 I/System.out: 0 {
2023-08-17 08:19:59.996 I/System.out:    id=1
2023-08-17 08:19:59.996 I/System.out:    workname=My First Work Record
2023-08-17 08:19:59.996 I/System.out:    logoid=1
2023-08-17 08:19:59.996 I/System.out:    year=17-08-2023
2023-08-17 08:19:59.996 I/System.out:    workinghours=0
2023-08-17 08:19:59.996 I/System.out: }
2023-08-17 08:19:59.996 I/System.out: 1 {
2023-08-17 08:19:59.996 I/System.out:    id=2
2023-08-17 08:19:59.996 I/System.out:    workname=My Other First Work Record
2023-08-17 08:19:59.996 I/System.out:    logoid=2
2023-08-17 08:19:59.996 I/System.out:    year=2023-08-17
2023-08-17 08:19:59.997 I/System.out:    workinghours=10
2023-08-17 08:19:59.997 I/System.out: }
2023-08-17 08:19:59.997 I/System.out: <<<<<
```

- the first dump (first few lines) shows that there is no data in the cursor.
- the second dump confirms that the data has been inserted and successfully extracted.

Using Android Studio's `App Inspection` :-

[image]